# How can I append just just the path?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, arraylist

I want to add the path of several txt files.
This is my output: "<_io.TextIOWrapper name='(path to txt file)' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>"
I just need the path, not the mode or encoding.

```
import os
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
from config import cred
import mmap

path = (r"mypath")
dirfiles = []

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    with open(os.path.join(path, filename)) as f:
        try:
            dirfiles.append(f)
            print(dirfiles)      
        except:
            pass
```

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: Why are you opening the file if you just want to print the path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just trying to print the path

```
for filename in os.listdir(path):
  print(os.path.join(path, filename))
```